# Passing a code block as an anon. function

Tags: bash, function

Is it possible to treat a block of commands as an anonymous function?

```
function wrap_this {
   run_something
   # Decide to run block or maybe not.
   run_something else
}

wrap_this {
   do_something
   do_somthing else
}

# Do something else

wrap_this {
   do_something_else_else
   do_something_else_else_else
}
```

(I realize you create a function or file for each block, but I find this option clearer and easier to read in certain situations.)

`while` does it with `do/done` and `function` does it with `{ multiple lines }`. I realize BASH does not have anonymous functions, but is it possible to pass multiple commands to another function, like you can do when defining a function or `while`?

Comment: Do you mean you want to decorate (in Python parlance) - i.e., return a function from a function? Your example, syntactically, isn't even BASH: is wrap_this supposed to be a function or a function call?

Comment: It is unclear to me what you want to do. As Mel pointed out, what you have written even syntactically valid, but it is unclear to me how what you have written relates to anonymous functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the shortest solution that I could think of:

Given these functions:

```bash
# List processing
map() { while IFS='' read -r x; do "$@" "$x"; done; }
filter() { while IFS='' read -r x; do "$@" "$x" >&2 && echo "$x"; done; }
foldr() { local f="$1"; local result="$2"; shift 2;  while IFS='' read -r x; do result="$( "$f" "$@" "$x" "$result" )"; done; echo "$result"; }
foldl() { local f="$1"; local result="$2"; shift 2;  while IFS='' read -r x; do result="$( "$f" "$@" "$result" "$x" )"; done; echo "$result"; }

# Helpers
re() { [[ "$2" =~ $1 ]]; }
```

Examples:

```bash
# Example helpers
toLower() { tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'; }
showStructure() { [[ "$1" == "--curly" ]] && echo "{$2; $3}" || echo "($1, $2)"; }

# All lib* directories, ignoring case, using regex
ls /usr | map toLower | filter re 'lib.*'

# All block devices. (Using test, for lack of a full bash [[ … ]].)
cd /dev; ls | filter test -b

# Show difference between foldr and foldl
$ ls / | foldr showStructure '()'
(var/, (usr/, (tmp/, (sys/, (sbin/, (run/, (root/, (proc/, (opt/, (mnt/, (media/, (lost+found/, (lib64/, (lib32/, (lib@, (home/, (etc/, (dev/, (daten/, (boot/, (bin/, ())))))))))))))))))))))
$ ls / | foldr showStructure '{}' --curly
{var/; {usr/; {tmp/; {sys/; {sbin/; {run/; {root/; {proc/; {opt/; {mnt/; {media/; {lost+found/; {lib64/; {lib32/; {lib@; {home/; {etc/; {dev/; {daten/; {boot/; {bin/; {}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}
```

(These examples are of course just usage examples, and in reality, this style would only make sense for more complicated use cases.)

Generally, the following style can always be used:

```bash
f() { something "$@"       ; }; someList    | map    f
g() { something "$1" "$2" …; }; someCommand | filter g
⋮                              ⋮            ⋮     ⋮
```

It’s not *quite* lambda, but it is very very close. Only a few excess characters.

But any of the following convenience abbreviations does not work as far as I can tell:

```bash
λ() { [[ $@ ]]; } # fails on spaces
λ() { [[ "${@:-1}" ${@:1:-1} ]]; } # syntax error
alias λ=test # somehow ignored
```

Unfortunately, `bash` is not very well suited for this style, even though some of its features have a very functional style.

Comment: Features of bash have functional style? The only thing _remotely_ functional is that bash (as pretty much any shell language) supports a form of function composition by piping output of one command into input of another. That's more of a feature of the general design of Unix though, not bash per se.

Answer (score 5):

I've managed to do what you want with a `eval` hack.
With this I lay warned that **eval is insecure and you should avoid at all costs**. Having that said, if you trust your code won't be abused, you can use this:

```
wrap_this(){
    run_something
    eval "$(cat /dev/stdin)"
    run_something_else
}
```

This allows you to run code as follows:

```
wrap_this << EOF
    my function
EOF
```

Not exactly ideal, since the inner block is a string, but does create reuse.

Comment: This is awesome! I would just add quotes around the first `!!` so as to prevent substitution in heredoc.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27920806/how-to-avoid-heredoc-expanding-variables

Comment: any reason why would wouldn't: source /dev/stdin ?

Answer (score 4):

No, bash doesn't have anonymous functions. It is however possible to pass a function name and arguments as strings and have bash call it.

```
function wrap() {
    do_before
    "$@"
    do_after
}

wrap do_something with_arguments
```

This is however, somewhat limited. Dealing with quoting can become a problem. Passing more than one command is also a complication.

Comment: Not a nightname, all you have to do is change `$*` to `"$@"`

Comment: Multi-line function bodies should work fine with this method.

Comment: Glenn, I forgot about that form, thanks. It doesn't completely solve the quoting problem though. Evan, a single command wrapped over multiple lines would work fine, I meant having more than one command in the body as per the examples in the question. I'll update my answer to address both comments.

Comment: This form works _very_ well if you take care to define functions that take simple arguments, and then pass calls to those functions as arguments. I.e. `wrap my_func "$arg1" "$arg2"`. My one quibble with this example is that the return value of "$@" is lost, but that's easily remedied. It may be desirable to wrap "$@" with `()` to ensure environmental changes don't leak, at some forking performance cost.

Answer (score 2):

You can put code in a string and pass it to `eval` or `sh` or simply interpolate it.

```
perform () {
  "$@"
}

perform echo "moo"
```

You can quickly end up in deep quoting trouble, though.

Comment: Actually, I was looking for `perform { echo "moo" \n echo "moo moo" \n echo "moo moo moo" }`. I already knew you can pass one command. But, I'm looking for multiple lines, not just one command or one line. Thanks though for trying.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `unset` to remove a function immediately after defining and using it. While this does not create a truly-anonymous function, the function will not be usable outside the immediate vicinity of the call-site.

```bash
function anon_fn {
    echo 123
}
anon_fn
unset anon_fn
```